# Как вписать свое название SSL сертификата (то название что в chrome слева от адреса сайта)?

Tags: ssl, https

Как вписать свое название SSL сертификата, которое отображается рядом со строкой URL?

Пример: http://joxi.ru/D2P5YLLCp9XpDA

Можно ли назвать сертификат - "Brand Name 2019"?

Comment: [EV-сертификаты мертвы](https://habr.com/post/425261/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это определенный тип сертификата (EV SSL сертификат). Такие сертификаты подтверждаются на юридическое лицо и рядом с url строкой будет название фирмы, НО не произвольная строка.

> EV SSL сертификат (Extended Validation Certificate) — сертификат с
>   расширенной проверкой выдачи. Самый престижный, надежный и дорогой тип
>   сертификатов предназначенный для веб-сайтов для протокола HTTPS,
>   которое доказывает что сайт принадлежит существующему юридическому
>   лицу (организации, компании, или корпорации).
>
> Получение данного сертификата требует расширенной проверки подлинности
>   центром сертификации. При проверке проверяются документы о
>   регистрации, налоговая документация, сотрудники службы поддержки,
>   телефон, владение доменом и род деятельности компании. Физические
>   лица, индивидуальные предприниматели и другие предприниматели не могут
>   получить сертификат данного типа.

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]